# How to pass 'this' view to DataBinding?

Tags: android, android-databinding

is it possible to pass **this** view to Data Binding.

For example, I want to write something like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    bind:imageUrl="@{model.imageUrl(this.width, this.height)}" 
/>
```

Comment: No, but you can take your **ImageView** as parameter in your `BindingAdapter` method.

Comment: @JeelVankhede Thanks for response, but I need the w and h to generate the url. BindingAdapter does not help me with that. Need to find another way.

Comment: "I need the w and h to generate the url" -- call `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` on the `ImageView` that is passed in as a parameter to the `BindingAdapter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing `(this.width, this.height)`, you can pass the reference of the view itself like (give android:id to your imageview)

```
bind:imageUrl="@{model.imageUrl(idOfImageView}"
```

and in your method you can get the height and width from the view itself.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you've got your custom **BindingAdapter** method like below :

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
public static void setImageUrl(ImageView view) {
      //Now get image view instance to provide width and height.
}
```

Check [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters#custom-logic).

Comment: I already have adapter
    @BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
    fun load(imageView: ImageView, imageUrl: String) {
       ....
    }
but imageUrl should be generated from another place.

Comment: Then you can pass it from **xml** if you've available that variable in data bracket.

Answer (score 0):

This is how @BindingAdapter annotation is used to load image by data binding

In your layout tag add this line

```
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Here is your ImageView

```
  <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:loadImage="@{imageUrl}"/>


@BindingAdapter({"loadImage"})
public static void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String imageUrl) {

 // Load image with your image loading library ,like with Glide or Picasso or any of your favourite

}
```